# Observable.Using with async Task

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive

I have used Observable.Using with methods that return an IDisposable in the way:

```
Observable.Using(() => new Stream(), s => DoSomething(s));
```

But how would we proceed when the stream is created asynchronously? Like in this:

```
Observable.Using(async () => await CreateStream(), s => DoSomething(s));

async Task<Stream> CreateStream() 
{
    ...
}

DoSomething(Stream s)
{
    ...
}
```

This doesn't compile because it says that `s` is `Task<Stream>` instead a `Stream`.

What's the deal?

Comment: Doing `Observable.Using(async () => await CreateStream(), s => DoSomething(s.Result));` does work, but it seems very wrong. This is an excellent question. I look forward to the answer.

Comment: Ah, can you try this: `Observable.Using(async () => await CreateStream(), s => Observable.FromAsync(() => s).SelectMany(x => DoSomething(x)))`?

Comment: @Enigmativity RE: `s.Result` I agree it feels very wrong. I think the idea is that the second function is supposed to use the resource asynchronously. You can write `Observable.Using(async (ct) => await CreateStream(), async (s, ct) => await DoSomething(s))`, that `ct` is for `CancellationToken` and it is required to resolve the overload. Very confusing IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take a look at the source for the async overload of `Observable.Using`:

```
Observable.FromAsync(resourceFactoryAsync)
    .SelectMany(resource => Observable.Using(() => resource, r =>
        Observable.FromAsync(ct => observableFactoryAsync(r, ct)).Merge()));
```

Knowing that it's just using the synchronous version under the hood, you can do something like this to adapt it to your usage:

```
Observable.FromAsync(CreateStream)
    .SelectMany(stream => Observable.Using(() => stream, DoSomething));
```

It's unfortunate an overload for this isn't included, but you could always create your own:

```
public static class ObservableEx
{
    public static IObservable<TSource> Using<TSource, TResource>(
        Func<Task<TResource>> resourceFactoryAsync,
        Func<TResource, IObservable<TSource>> observableFactory)
        where TResource : IDisposable =>
        Observable.FromAsync(resourceFactoryAsync).SelectMany(
            resource => Observable.Using(() => resource, observableFactory));
}
```

and then it's as simple as:

```
ObservableEx.Using(CreateStream, DoSomething);
```

All of this is assuming that `DoSomething` returns an observable, which is not mentioned in your question but is required by the contract of `Observable.Using`.

Comment: Why does the question have 5 upvotes but this answer had just 1? It is a great answer.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem here is that there are two overloads with very awkward type signatures.

When you pass a `Task<TResource>` returning function as the first argument it seems to infer that the second argument, the "observable factory", is also going to return a `Task` but inference then fails because, in your example, there is no parameter declared for cancellation token by either function and both *require* that parameter. Inference fails in a myriad of ways and it gets confusing.

I will try to put it into perspective with an example that is realistic.

**Note:** writing code like the following is probably a bad idea but it is at least real world type use case.

```
var connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;app=LINQPad";

Observable.Using(
        resourceFactoryAsync: async ct => await ConnectAsync(connectionString, ct),
        observableFactoryAsync: async (connection, ct) => await QueryAsync(connection, ct)
    )
    .Subscribe(
        onNext: Console.WriteLiner,
        onError: Console.Error.WriteLine
    );

async Task<IObservable<string>> QueryAsync(SqlConnection c, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    var command = c.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "select * from Categories as c order by c.CategoryId";
    var enumerableQuery = 
        from IDataRecord record in await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(ct)
        select (string)record["CategoryName"];
    return enumerableQuery.ToObservable();
}

async Task<SqlConnection> ConnectAsync(string cs, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection(cs);
    await connection.OpenAsync(ct);
    return connection;
}
```

**Note:** to the use of named arguments is just to document which overload is being selected.

That was the best I could come up with but feel free to edit this with better examples.

Somethings that are noteworthy are

- All of this comes crashing down completely, compilation failing, if a nullary function is provided for either `resourceFactoryAsync`, or `observableFactoryAsync`. You must declare the `CancellationToken` as a formal parameter of both the resource factory and the observable factory functions. They are both named `ct` in the code above for the sake of brevity. While we are just passing them along, what matters is that they are *declared*.
- notice that the `connection` parameter of the `observableFactoryAsync` is not an awaitable but the actual resource. The error you received, prompting you to naturally assume that the resource should be awaited, was due to type inference selecting the synchronous overload and thus forwarding `TResource` as a `Task<X>` into the next function which was also assumed to be synchronous.
- The way these abstractions compose feels rather awkward, at least to me. We are mixing multiple asynchronous and synchronous programming styles and we have `IDisposable`s mixed up into it such that we are creating them explicitly, asynchronously, but who knows how they will be disposed.
- The `QueryAsync` function actually creates a secondary `IDisposable`, an `SqlCommand`, which I would normally wrap in a `using` block but cannot because I need the lazy evaluation of the query preserved and so I need the command to not have been disposed when the closure returned is called.
- There is probably a better way to do this, but I wonder if it involves calling `Observable.Using` multiple times and then merging them. I am basically just rambling right now about how complicated the Observable monad can feel (granted I am a novice Rx user) but it really feels like it wants your entire application to be wrapped inside of it.